# PHP array_search in multidimensional array by variable

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have an array where I want to filter out all the information about a OrderId. Therefore I want to array_search my array by a variable that has my OrderId in it.
This way I can obtain the array key and then slice the array with array_slice.

```
Array
( 
    [Order] => Array
        ( 
            [0] => Array
                ( 
                    [OrderId] => 4832413060 
                    [DateTimeCustomer] => 2018-07-17T12:55:07.000+02:00 
                    [DateTimeDropShipper] => 2018-07-17T12:55:07.000+02:00 
                    [CustomerDetails] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [ShipmentDetails] => Array 
                                ( 
                                    [SalutationCode] => 01 
                                    [Firstname] => name 
                                    [Surname] => sirname 
                                    [Streetname] => streetname 
                                    [Housenumber] => number 
                                    [ZipCode] => zipcode 
                                    [City] => city 
                                    [CountryCode] => countryCode
                                    [Email] => email 
                                ) 
                            [BillingDetails] => Array 
                                ( 
                                    [SalutationCode] => 01 
                                    [Firstname] => name
                                    [Surname] => sirname
                                    [Streetname] => streetname 
                                            [Housenumber] => number 
                                    [ZipCode] => zipcode 
                                    [City] => city 
                                    [CountryCode] => countryCode 
                                    [Email] => email
                                ) 
                        ) 
                    [OrderItems] => Array
                        ( 
                            [OrderItem] => Array 
                                ( 
                                    [OrderItemId] => orderitemid 
                                    [OfferReference] => Array 
                                        ( 

                                        ) 
                                    [EAN] => ean 
                                    [Title] => title 
                                    [Quantity] => 1 
                                    [OfferPrice] => 14.95 
                                    [TransactionFee] => 3.24 
                                    [LatestDeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18+02:00 
                                )
                        )
                ) 
            [1] => Array
                ( 
                    [OrderId] => 4832413070
                    [DateTimeCustomer] => 2018-07-17T12:55:07.000+02:00 
                    [DateTimeDropShipper] => 2018-07-17T12:55:07.000+02:00 
                    [CustomerDetails] => Array 
                        ( 
                            [ShipmentDetails] => Array 
                                ( 
                                    [SalutationCode] => 01 
                                    [Firstname] => name 
                                    [Surname] => sirname 
                                    [Streetname] => streetname 
                                    [Housenumber] => number 
                                    [ZipCode] => zipcode 
                                    [City] => city 
                                    [CountryCode] => countryCode
                                    [Email] => email 
                                ) 
                            [BillingDetails] => Array 
                                ( 
                                    [SalutationCode] => 01 
                                    [Firstname] => name
                                    [Surname] => sirname
                                    [Streetname] => streetname 
                                    [Housenumber] => number 
                                    [ZipCode] => zipcode 
                                    [City] => city 
                                    [CountryCode] => countryCode 
                                    [Email] => email
                                ) 
                        ) 
                    [OrderItems] => Array
                        ( 
                            [OrderItem] => Array 
                                ( 
                                    [OrderItemId] => orderitemid 
                                    [OfferReference] => Array 
                                        ( 

                                        ) 
                                    [EAN] => ean 
                                    [Title] => title 
                                    [Quantity] => 1 
                                    [OfferPrice] => 14.95 
                                    [TransactionFee] => 3.24 
                                    [LatestDeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18+02:00 
                                )
                        )
                )
```

The code I tried:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
$key = array_search($item, $array1);
```

$item is the same as the OrderId.

I have tried many different examples from the internet, but unfortunatly nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: I can't see your array because of the formatting. Can you edit the question and make it more readable so we can help?

Comment: try something like `foreach ($items['Order'] as $index => $item) {` then `$item['OrderId']` will be the data you want so use it to check whatever (not sure I understand what you check it against, or what `$array1` is)

Comment: Can you json_encode the array and post that so that we can use the array data

Comment: Are all orderids unique? Or can the same orderid appear again ?

Comment: Has OP gone *wim salabim* and disappeared?

Comment: Hey sorry, was away for a while. Thank you guys for the reactions so far. I will try all your suggestions tomorrow.

Comment: If you do not convert your XML to an array you can use Xpath on it.

Comment: @WimSalabim have you tried the answers?

Answer (score 0):

`array_search()` is not appropriate for multidimensional arrays. Use `array_filter()`

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $found = array_filter($array, function($element) use($item) {
        return $element['OrderId'] == $item;
    }
    // $found now contains all the elements in the original array for $item
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use array_column to make the array associative with orderid as the key thus finding the orderid very easily.
But this assumes you only have unique orderids in the array.

```
$find = 4832413060;
$arr = array_column($arr, NULL, 'orderid');

$findOrder = $arr[$find];

Var_dump($findOrder);
```

I made a small array to demonstrate the code.
https://3v4l.org/jEus3

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't work. I get "NULL" as a response.

Comment: @WimSalabim there can be two reasons for that. **1** the orderid does not exist in the array. **2** you have implemented the code incorrectly. Since you have not included the array in such a way that we can use it, I can't test the code on the real data. If you include the array in json format then I can test it on the real data. But I don't see how my example array differs enough to make a difference.